# String to Date in AWS Glue with Data Frames

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, casting, aws-glue

I'm trying to convert/cast a column within a data frame from string to date with no success, here is part of the code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_unixtime, unix_timestamp, col
from datetime import datetime

## Dynamic Frame to Data Frame
df = Transform0.toDF()

## Substring of time column
## Before: "Thu Sep 03 2020 01:43:52 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)""
df = df.withColumn('date_str', substring(df['time'],5,20))
## After: "Sep 03 2020 01:43:52"

## I have tried the following statements with no success
## I use show() in order to see in logs the result

df.withColumn('date_str', datetime.strptime('date_str', '%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S')).show()
df.withColumn(col('date_str'), from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col('date_str'),"%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S"))).show()
df.withColumn('date_str', to_timestamp('date_str', '%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S')).show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to assign it to another data frame variable .

eg:

```
df = df.withColumn(column, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col('date_str'), 'yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss')).cast(
                    types.TimestampType()))
df.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, Yes, I need to assign it to another column in data frame, I'll try that one.

Comment: Thanks Emerson, it worked, just I did an small change:
df = df.withColumn('date_new', from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col('date_str'), 'MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss')).cast(TimestampType()))

Answer (score 0):

Try using [spark datetime](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html) formats while using spark functions `to_timestamp()...etc` functions.

**`Example:`**

```
 df.show()
#+--------------------+
#|                  ts|
#+--------------------+
#|Sep 03 2020 01:43:52|
#+--------------------+

df.withColumn("ts1",to_timestamp(col("ts"),"MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss")).show()
#+--------------------+-------------------+
#|                  ts|                ts1|
#+--------------------+-------------------+
#|Sep 03 2020 01:43:52|2020-09-03 01:43:52|
#+--------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, let me try that one and let you know.

Comment: Thanks "notNull" , it worked, looks like the "mask" I was using was not the correct one. It worked.